# Retrieving Entity Performance in JPA

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

Below is the code I used to retrieve Profile entity:

```
    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    return em.find(Profile.class, email);
```

If Profile have a lot of properties and some are List or Set and if I only need 3 String properties (e.g., Last Name, First Name, birthday), is it okay to retrieve using the above code or I have to write a query retrieving only those 3 properties?

By the way, the application is run under Google App Engine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think AppEngine doesn't allow you to select only 3 properties from an entity.
All entities stored in AppEngine will be considered as a unit that you can't spit it up.

However, if the Profile entity has some child-entities, then it would be better not to fetch them.

Comment: how to NOT fecth child-entities?

Comment: I just realized you are doing it with JPA, a bit googling told me that JPA looks doesn't support fetch groups... In the case of JDO, by default it won't retrieve children entities unless specified so. I suspect it will be the same to JPA, but you need more look at JPA.